# Leaking shower even after handle change

Tags: shower, leak

So I have had a leaking shower head and I replaced the handle it and the inside parts with new springs and everything but for some reason it is still leaking. What could be the reasoning or what else can I check to see why it's still leaking.

Comment: Leak in another place or maybe a seat is damaged and needs to be ream/replace.

Comment: Manufacturer, and model, some pics maybe to help discern what type it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's also unclear if the shower head is leaking, or the valve.